# Does builtin flash player in Google Chrome on Linux x64 work?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, flash-player

I'm using Google Chrome on a Ubuntu 10.04 x64 system and I just finished doing an update which got me version 19.0.1084.46 of Chrome.  Now for the first time I see a message that says `Adobe Flash Player was blocked because it is out of date` when I open up a website that has flash.

When I clicked on the link to update the plugin it took me to a page that said: `If you are using the Google Chrome browser, Adobe® Flash® Player is built-in but has been disabled.`  I searched some and found another [page from Google](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=108086) that says that I should be using `libflashplayergc.so` as the plug-in that is integrated with Chrome.

However, I don't see that plugin in my system.  My question is, is this something that I should see?  Or is this plugin only for 32-bit systems and so I need to continue using the Adobe system plugin `libflashplayer.so`?

Comment: please, read my answer. I solved the problem like that.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome(+flash) should work on 64bit OS w/o problems.
Do you get that message with some specific site or every site that has flash? Can you watch youtube videos or play games/video on newgrounds.com?
If you go to chrome://plugins/ you should see pepper listed there.

Comment: Flash does work when I downloaded Flash Player from Adobe and put `libflashplayer.so` in `/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so`.  But what I'm wondering about is whether the built-in version of the player that Chrome's help page lists `libflashplayergc.so` works on 64-bit Linux, because it is missing on my system.  Also I don't see `pepper` listed either.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Fedora 16 a number of times and when I add Google Chrome (Ver 19.0.1084.46-135956) it has out of five times only installed the supposedly included libflashplayer once. This on new systems with new drives. Would be nice to know what controls that. (From google-chrome repo.)

When I install flash-plugin-11.2.202.233-release the result is the web page that has flash on it will show it on most applications that are located in the same location (as flash) and the flash material will become a live background image on those applications. Does not matter which flash site. I have 9 desktops and dual monitors.

As soon as I remove flash that phenomena goes away. (From adobe-linux-x86_64 repo.)

Comment: this doesn't seem like an answer to the question. it seems more like another question, please post as a question and not in the answer field of another question

Comment: what kinda answer is this????

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem right now.

as the Adobe says [here](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/?no_redirect):

```
Note: Adobe Flash Player 11.2 will be the last version to target Linux as a supported platform.
Adobe will continue to provide security backports to Flash Player 11.2 for Linux.
```

So, if you look in your `/opt/google/chrome/`you'll find a *PepFlash* directory, where inside there is a .so file (`libpepflashplayer.so`). You have to delete that folder and create a new folder called *plugins* where you put inside the `libflashplayer.so` downloadable from the link above.

If you don't want to delete the PepFlash dir, you must anyway have the libflashplayer.so as I told you (the 11.2 version, 'cause the 11.5 does not work in linux as the Adobe explain), but you have to disable the `libpepflashplayer.so`.

Go to **`chrome://plugins/`** and disable the PepFlash version and the 11.5 version.

I think you might have this kinda situation:

[image: google-chrome plugins]

Let me know if you'll resolve this issue.